# ArabXeTeX-like interface for lualatex

Tags: luatex, arabic

I would like to know if and how it would be possible to parse and convert ArabXeTeX ascii input to unicode under LuaLaTeX.  I came across the ḍād package by Yannis Haralambous, but as far as I know there is no “arabluatex” package, namely some arabxetex-like package for LuaLaTeX.

I would be very grateful if any expert could point me in the right direction.  I know how TECkit works, but I know nothing about font mapping under LuaLaTeX.

Many thanks in anticipation!